# Possible to export this to OBJ?

Tags: export

New to Blender. I've been following this tutorial on procedural clouds:
https://cloud.blender.org/p/spring/5b8d15945152ba40078ff0e6

I want to export these clouds to After Effects or BMD Fusion as an OBJ (or FBX), but when I try, they only come through as primitive shapes (which is how they display in Blender in the Solid view-- they only become clouds in the render view). Does this mean it's not possible?

Just to be clear, I have successfully exported objects (with materials) before, but they've been solid meshes with simple textures. I understand that this is more complex.

If it's relevant, here are the nodes involved:
Volume Density
Noise Texture
Subtract/Multiply/Add
Gradient Texture
Voronoi Texture
Mix
ColorRamp
Principled Volume
Material Output

Comment: your example is only availiable to blender cloud subribers. It would help getting better answers if you would use an accesible example.

Comment: if its a shader editor effects id say that it is not possible to export as obj or fbx both are relativly simple mesh formats.

Comment: you can search for sliced .exr as that would be an option for import (maybe) in both software pakeges (AE, Fusion). Maybe someone else can help you slicing your volume in blender, good luck ;)

Comment: @AM thank you! Here's a link to the project file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqqz5odb7ofyzw5/Procedural%20Clouds%20-%20Example%20Blender%20File.blend?dl=0